# Android: why would USB Host have stopped working after installing "rooted" system image?

Tags: android, usb

after I rooted a Nexus 10 the app I have written which connects to an Arduino in USB Host mode no longer works properly. I'm pretty sure this is because the USB Host mode is no longer available.

I have checked the original unrooted device with Chainfire's 'USB Host Diagnostics' tool and it recognises the plugged in Arduino whilst scanning for connected devices, but nothing is detected after rooting.

Originally the device had Android 4.3 - build JWR66Y, and USB Host mode worked.
I rooted via the Nexus Root Toolkit and installed a rooted image of the same build, now the device isn't detected.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: This question is off topic here, as the issue is with the custom system image developed by someone else breaking USB host support, rather than with your code.  As a result it should be migrated to android stackexchange to be handled as a custom ROM / system configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of your app not working. I have seen it plenty of times that when someone roots a device the USB host no longer works. Its a problem with the ROM or method that was used to root the device. Best bet is to reset the device and try something else.